# nix rebuild switch cause "fchmod() of /tmp/.X11-unix failed: Read-only file system"

Tags: nix, nixos

I have restart on WSL my installation from scratch:

```
 wsl --unregister Nixos
 wsl --import NixOS .\NixOS\ nixos-wsl-installer.tar.gz --version 2
 wsl -s Nixos
 wsl
```

nixos-wsl-installer.tar.gz comes from
https://github.com/nix-community/NixOS-WSL/releases/tag/22.05-5c211b47

instalation done. nixos has started

I haven't changed anything in /etc/nixos/configuration.nix yet

```
  sudo nixos-rebuild switch
```

> fchmod() of /tmp/.X11-unix failed: Read-only file system

What does it mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something to do with being in WSL - `sudo mount -o remount,rw /tmp/.X11-unix` seems to fix it.

See [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9303)